# Is it possible to create a template literal from a normal string?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a template literal from a normal string? e.g. from a definition in some JSON.

```
var foo = 'world';
var string = "hello ${foo}";
var string2 = `${string}`; // "hello ${foo}" - but I want "hello world"
```

Comment: You string has `"hello ${foo}"` cause you didn't used the backticks to enclose  `string`. It will be treated as normal string. Enclose them in back tick

Comment: Yes - that is the crux of my question. My best guess currently would be to use `eval` and include the backtracks in the JSON.

Comment: Ahh! I see, but if you include backticks inside a string, it will be considered part of string, it won't be interpreted as template literal.